# Has anyone deployed a .NET WinForms application to Japan

Tags: sql, winforms, sql-server-2008

Do any developers out there have any experience developing and  deploying a .NET Windows Forms application to Japan, using Kanji, Hiragana, and Katakana Japanese language scripts?  I am wondering what impacts need to be considered for validating data, inserting/updating, searching and sorting data using SQL Server 2008.  What are some things to look out for other than setting the .NET culture namespace along with using resx files to display language values on windows forms.

Any information and guidance in this area is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: One issue is that a english programmer/tester is unlickly to be able to see if the text is correct on lables etc, so think about how you will do QA.

Comment: try to avoid getting listed @ http://engrishfunny.failblog.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use NVARCHAR in the DB!

There quite a lot to it, in the past I've found quite a few [useful](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663) [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx).

Also make sure you follow [best](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291552%28VS.71%29.aspx) [practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7x1y988.aspx) <--- really useful!

Comment: yes, I was aware that you want to make sure that all your text fields should be nvarchar to support unicode.  Thanks for the reminder.